# can't reach inner inner object using keyvalue pair in Angular with firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, key-value

I have a json object that has an inner object called data, which has data: {count: 9, message: "9 sites synced"} - also json object. I'm trying to get the value from message, not from count. Here is my template code:

```
<div class="full-width border-radius-4 overflow-hidden">
  <!-- Header -->
  <div class="head accent p-24 pb-16" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="space-between">
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="end center">
    </div>
  </div>
  <mat-accordion class="full-width example-headers-align" multi *ngIf="liveActions$ | async as actions; else: loading">
    <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let action of actions">
      <mat-expansion-panel-header *ngIf="action.type == 'single'">
        <mat-panel-description fxFlex="30%">
          <div class="lgreen material-icons" *ngIf="action.status  == 'completed'">done_all</div>
          <div class="red material-icons" *ngIf="action.status == 'pending'">pending_actions</div>
          <div class="blue material-icons" *ngIf="action.status == 'queued'">pending</div>
          <div class="yellow material-icons" *ngIf="action.status == 'error'">error</div>
        </mat-panel-description>
        <mat-panel-description fxFlex="40%">{{action.key}}</mat-panel-description>
        <div *ngFor="let dataItem of action?.data | keyvalue">{{dataItem?.value?.message}}
        </div>
        <!--        <mat-panel-description>{{action.startDate | date:'medium'}}</mat-panel-description>-->
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      </div>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
  </mat-accordion>
  <ng-template #loading>Loading&hellip;</ng-template>
</div>
```

when I do {{dataItem?.value?.message}} I get nothing. When I do dataItem.value, I get the values for both count and message.

I need only the value from message. What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with **keyvalue** pipe on your object it will convert the action.data  object to below array

```
[{key:count, value: 9}, {key:message,value:'9 sites synced'}]
```

if you iterate over the above object :

```
dataItem?.value?.message = undefined
dataItem.value = 9 and 9 sites synced
```

Which is what u r seeing.

You can just add a condition when binding the value what to show

```
{{ dataItem.key === 'message' ? dataItem.value: ' '}}
```

there are other ways also...I think you can figure out now what was happening and what needs to be done as per your requirement.